# visual studio 2012 SQL CLR

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create, test and deploy a SQL CLR (database project) using Visual Studio 2012 (update 2) and it is getting very frustrating.

The coding itself was trivial but now I cannot deploy or execute unit tests on the project.  I have developed SQL CLR in VS 2010 and it was much simpler (Test.sql).

So here are my questions:

1. **How does one set up a local SQL script to test the newly minted functions/sprocs?** [I have tried adding a .sql file and marking it to be run on debug but I get error SQL71006.]
2. **How does one deploy the project?**  I am deploying to SQL 2008 R2 and I know I need to use .NET 2.0 but I still have not been able to deploy anything. When I execute the generated .SQL on the target SQL Server instance, nothing happens (no errors, nothing).

This has worked so well with previous versions of Visual Studio one wonders if MSFT is perhaps now trying to discourage the generation of SQL CLR modules?

Comment: You should try installing SSDT [(Sql Server Data Tools)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) for VS2012

Answer (score 3):

For first point, ensure that *.sql* file in properties has anything then Build in field **Action**

For second point, try to use a **Publish** option, where you will get a dialog box to set up database connection and other config option.

**Deploy** option does nothing when you work with database projects.